# enterpriseアカウントでの配布（in-house）がうまくいかない。

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Xcode6.3.2 (6D2105)にてin-houseによる配布をしようとしています。

Save for Enterprize Deploymentでアーカイブしようとすると以下アラートが出て完了できません。

> To save for Enterprise Deployment You need add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program for the development team "XXXXXXXXXX".

EnterpriseのApple IDを設定済みにもかかわらず、上記のアラートがでています。
どなたか解決策ご存じでしょうか。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/10164 マルチポスト

Answer (score 0):

teamの設定が間違っている取るようです。プロジェクト設定のGenetalタブのteamを設定する箇所があります（version番号を設定する辺です）。この設定をNoneにするかEnterprise用のApple IDにするとアーカイブできると思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。
そこはEnterpriseのAppleIDを設定済なんですが、できないんですよね。。

Answer (score 0):

下記Webページの手順の通り、Apple Developer Enterprise Programに登録済みのAppleIDをXcodeに登録されていますでしょうか。

[Adding Your Account to Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html)